# Can't install mongodb doctrine in symfony2 with composer

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

I've followed the official [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html)

when I run composer update I have this error : 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
    - doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA9 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4].
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA9 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0-BETA9].
```

When I run `php -m` I can't find mongo extension , but the server is running and I can use Mongo in PHP, does anyone know what should the problem be ? 
I doubt that the doctrine can't find the mongo extension..
thanks !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I fixed it ! 
As expected, it was because of the extension so here are the steps to take if you face the same problem as me : `the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.`

1. run the command : `php --ini`, you will see all the configuration files parsed! For me , I am using PHP-fpm , I thought the only php.ini file needed was inside fpm folder, but I was wrong there was a php.ini file inside CLI folder and it's this folder that tells the server which modules are loaded , and it's exactly the same file that doctrine reads the extensions from.
2. Open CLI/php.ini and add this line in the end `extension=mongo.so`.
3. Restart PHP : `service php5-fpm restart`

That's it!

Comment: I get this same error but I'm not sure on how you fixed it.. Can you explain some more? Open CLI/php.ini. Is that in terminal or is that a directory (if so I can't find it). Neither step 3 does anything for me (assuming it is a terminal command again). Service command not found.  I followed the same documentation you mentioned. I'm working with mamp on mac btw.

Answer (score 1):

for OSX:

```
brew install php56-mongo
```

if it errors out: read the error message carefully and follow it to rerun the command.

source:

http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx

Comment: the problem is the cli interface that seems to use different php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

#### Linux

To install PHP's MongoDB extension, run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongo
```

See also: [Easiest way to install Mongodb PHP extension in Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22459164/55075)