# Easiest way to install Mongodb PHP extension in Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy)?

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-13.10

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy salamander) and I was hoping that `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` would be enough to get the mongodb database driver installed.

No such luck though. I'm using php5-fpm, so firstly I found I also needed to do `php5enmod mongo` but even with that, I get a error:

```
include(MongoClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Instead, to install I have to do the following (which uses a lot more disk space):

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-dev make php-pear
 sudo pecl install mongo
 sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini
```

My question is why isn't  `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` enough? Is it a problem with the Ubuntu repo? How can I look into the ubuntu repositories and find what version it uses or why `MongoClient.php` isn't included. I'm using the "`ubuntu:saucy`" docker image as my base and it includes universe by default I think.

Comment: You don't have to include a PHP script to use MongoDB. Open a `phpinfo()` and verify your module got loaded. Keep in mind that different PHP environments use different `php.ini`s. (`/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`)

Comment: apt-get isn't enough because every PHP setup is different

Comment: also php5-mongo is probably a really old version of the driver, you should be using pecl install mongo

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04, `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` results in a fully working mongo PHP extension. So I guess there is just a packaging problem in Ubuntu 13.10 which causes the problem.

**Solution**: Use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instead of Ubuntu 13.10.

But, if you *have* to use Ubuntu 13.10, don't use the `php5-mongo` Ubuntu package, instead install the mongo extension via pecl:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev make php-pear
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini
```

Comment: This line `sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini` fails for me. It says permission denied when executing `tee` However I changed it to this `sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" | sudo tee /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini`

Comment: If you want this module to be loaded in both apache and cli you'd the need to symlink it properly. `ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/mongo.ini /etc/php5/cli/mongo.ini` and another symlink for apache

Answer (score 34):

The easiest to install the mongoDB driver for php5 in ubuntu is using the command :

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mongo
```

Attention, the driver is correctly installed but not loaded yet, so should absolutly restart the server, if using apache should do :

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks but while your instructions would work on todays Ubuntu, they won't work on Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).

Answer (score 3):

There is also a good way to install the mongo DB for PHP. I have ubuntu 14.04LTS.

```
open synaptic package manager and search "mongo"
```

select these packages to install.

- php-horde-mongo
- php-mongo

[image: synaptic package manager]

click apply to install the packages.

Now restart you apache2 using this command.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

### Test the mongo

create the PHP file with name mongo-test.php and paste this code there.

```
<?php
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();

   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->mydb;

   echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

test this URL http://localhost/mongo-test.php

Comment: On Ubuntu 15.04, I used Software Center to find php-horde-mongo and php5-mongo. After installation, I restarted the Apache. And it worked perfectly. Thanks for providing the test code as well :)

Comment: welcome. Synaptic and software center used the same repository for packages. Synaptic is more advanced tool while Software center is simple and easy.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a packaging problem in Ubuntu.

Did you install PHP5-fpm via `apt-get` too? It looks like there is a disconnect between how you installed PHP5 and which php.ini file the php5-mongo package is trying to update.

As for the `include(MongoClient.php): failed to open stream` error; it is because of your autoloader.
When you do `new MongoClient` when the extension is not enabled it hits your autoloaded which tries to include a file called `<classname>.php`