# MongoDB with PHP7 and Symfony3

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, php-7

I have a problem with MongoDB. I want install MongoDBBundle in my Symfony App but composer return an error:

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.


 Problem 2
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.1.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.3 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.1 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.2 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.3 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.4 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.5 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.6 requires doctrine/mongodb ~1.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.x-dev].
- doctrine/mongodb 1.3.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.2.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.2.12 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- Installation request for doctrine/mongodb-odm ~1.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.1.0].
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu_bc.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-intl.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mongodb.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
- /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I don't understand this error because the extension MongoDB not missing. I have installed this extension with this command: 
pecl install mongodb

and when i list the php module load with `php -m`:

```
[PHP Modules]
apc
apcu
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mcrypt
mongodb
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
wddx
xdebug
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib
```

I try this solution:

```
echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Loaded Configuration" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`
```

But it is not the solution.

Thank you for your help.

Thibault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doctrine/mongodb 1.4.x-dev requires ext-mongo ^1.5
```

ext-mongo is the legacy MongoDB driver (\MongoClient). ext-mongo was never ported to Zend 3 (PHP7). The new Mongo driver that *does* work under PHP7 (the one you installed via PECL) is ext-mongodb. This is not supported by the Doctrine driver for MongoDB.

You have two choices: find a Doctrine driver that does work with the newer Mongo extension, or downgrade to PHP 5.6 and install ext-mongo.

There is a [currently open issue on support for the new extension](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/1292).

Answer (score 0):

Is the line extension=mongo.so In your CLI php.ini file, and uncommented? Might be worthwhile to check ALL your php.ini files. This issue apparently came up with Symfony 2 as well: [Can't install mongodb doctrine in symfony2 with composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869846/cant-install-mongodb-doctrine-in-symfony2-with-composer)

Comment: The line extension=mongo.so is uncommented the "php -m" return this warning: PHP Warning:  Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Hmph. THAT sounds like TWO mongo extensions... but from Fiskie's post, it seem this is a known issue with Doctrine, Mongo, and PHP 7...

Answer (score 0):

Ok i understand. For downgrade to PHP 5.6 the steps is: apt-get remove php7.0. apt-get install php5.6. The require for composer.json is okay ?

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.1.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
    "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.x-dev",
    "mongodb/mongodb": "dev-master",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "dev-composer-replace",
    "doctrine/mongodb": "1.4.x-dev",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "~1.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "~3.0"
},
```